# "Cannot find -lws2_32.lib" error in Code::Blocks on Windows

Tags: c

I'm trying to begin work on socket programming but can't seem to add ws_32.lib. I have gone to build options and added 'C:\MinGW\lib\libws2_32.a' to the link libraries list to no avail. I also went to the properties section of the project options and added the library there, which also didn't work.

Current Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main()
{

    WSADATA wsa;

    printf("\nInitializing Winsock...\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0) {

        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;

    }

    printf("Initialized");

    return 0;
}
```

Debug Log When Attempting to Compile:

```
||=== Build: Debug in sockets (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lws2_32.lib|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `-lws2_32`

Comment: You should just add `ws2_32` (without `.lib`) to the libraries of your codeblocks project and make sure `C:\MinGW\lib` is in the linker search paths in your gcc compiler settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `-lws2_32`. — [JCWasmx86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13912132/jcwasmx86)

You should just add `ws2_32` (without `.lib`) to the libraries of your codeblocks project and make sure `C:\MinGW\lib` is in the linker search paths in your gcc compiler settings. — [Brecht Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13912132/jcwasmx86)

Comment: I have added the ws2_32 to the linker and it compiles fine until I put the WSADATA wsa; line in and it says WSDATA was not declared in this scope. Any ideas?